# T-SQL return MAX field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have this code:

```
SELECT ItemID, UserID, MAX(LogID) AS 'LatestLog'
FROM Log
WHERE UserID <> 0
GROUP BY ItemID, UserID`
```

Now this returns the UserID to the latest log entry for a certain Item. I'd assume it would do the same when joining to another table that that has the Item ID that I'm joining to, like so:

```
SELECT it.ItemID, it.ItemName, UA.UserID
FROM ItemTable it LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ItemID, UserID, MAX(LogID) AS 'LatestLog'
      FROM Log
      WHERE UserID <> 0
      GROUP BY LogID, UserID
     ) AS UA
     ON it.ItemID = UA.ItemID
```

What happens with this code is that it returns the Max LogIDs for each user that modified the Item, instead of just the max LogID as I'd assume it would. What am I missing here?

I also created a Scalar Function where I would enter the Log table LogID and returns the userID and works, but after running it, it slows it down really bad, and I'm assuming that is due to querying all the LogID's from the initial table joining the ItemID.

```
DECLARE @UID INT
SELECT @UID = al.UserID FROM Log al WHERE al.LogID = @theID
RETURN @UID
```

And use it like so:

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemName, UDFGetModBy(MAX(UA.LogID)) FROM ItemTable it 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ItemID, UserID, MAX(LogID) AS 'LatestLog' FROM Log WHERE UserID <> 0
GROUP BY LogID, UserID) AS UA ON it.ItemID = UA.ItemID
```

Item Table schema consists of: `ItemID, ItemName, CreatedDate`
Log Table schema consists of: `LogID, ItemID (FK to Item Table), DateModified, 
UserID`

The expected output should be: `it.ItemID, it.ItemName, al.UserID, al.DateModified`

To clarify further: the Log Table saves a new LogID every time the Item has been modified by a user that is not the system (`UserID <> 0`).

Also tried:

```
SELECT it.ItemID, it.ItemName, UID = 
(SELECT al.UserID, MAX(al.LogID) AS 'LID' FROM Log al)  
WHERE al.UserID <> 0 AND it.ItemID = al.ItemID) 
FROM ItemTable it
```

But I get a 
`only one expression can be specified in  the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS` error

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Share `Item` and `Log` tables `Schema` and `Data`. And Expected `Output`.

Comment: I'm not sure you need a derived table at all to do this. And it will slow it down, you're doing it one by one in the function and taking it away from being set based.

Comment: I tried to answer, but realized we need your table definitions first.

Comment: @Leonidas199x That would be true in MySql or in SQL Server 2000 or earlier, but it is not true for DBMS's that have good statistical optimizers like SQL Server 2005+, Oracle or DB2.

Comment: @RBarryYoung interesting, do you know any reading material on it? Would be interested to understand how that works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter data inside the select. Something (do not have sql here) like this:

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemName, UDFGetModBy(MAX(UA.LogID)) FROM ItemTable it 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ItemID, UserID, MAX(LogID) AS 'LatestLog' FROM Log WHERE 
UserID <> 0 and ItemID = it.ItemID GROUP BY ItemID, UserID)
```

Using Outer Apply you can filter data in subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured you can do it this way in a sub-query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ItemTable ORDER BY DESC
```

This grabs the whole 'LatestLog' row I was looking for. Not sure if it's optimal, but it works for now.